# How does C# load / initialize classes? Problem with delegate returning null

Tags: c#, events, .net-core, loading, asp.net-core-webapi

`OnQueueAdvancePosition?.Invoke(this, advancePositionArgs);` returns null. In the constructor of a different class I am subscribing to the event like this `QueueService.OnQueueAdvancePosition += OnQueueAdvancePosition;`

Additional information:
I am currently working on a webapi hosted using an Azure web service, and I stumbled upon this problem when I had to share some data with a second class.
In my program I've got two service classes, QueueService and StationService, which work on different sets of documents in a CosmosDB, and I want to keep them as separate as possible, which is why I thought I'd use EventHandlers.

The OnQueueAdvancePosition is invoked in the QueueService class when a specific RESTful api is called. StationService also has it's own set of functions with corresponding restful api. (Or more specifically, when api/station/etc/etc is requested, a method in StationController.cs is executed, which then executes a method in StationService. Passing along the information gathered from the body like this):

```
public ChargingStatationUser Advance([FromBody]ChargingStatationUser applicant)
{
    return service.AdvanceQueue(applicant);
}
```

And the api looks like this:

```
api/station/etc/etc
api/queue/etc/etc
```

I have figured out how to circumvent OnQueueAdvancePosition being null, by making sure that a request to one of the apis under api/station/ is called before calling the one that will result in `OnQueueAdvancePosition?.Invoke(this, advancePositionArgs);` being executed.

My question is why does this happen? I'd like to learn more about what is going on here and how to make sure that my events are being subscribed to. It seems like an object of the StationService class isn't being constructed at runtime. Possibly because StationController doesn't exist?

The StationController class looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]/")]
[ApiController]
public class StationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly StationService service;

    public StationController(StationService context)
    {
        service = context;
    }
    // various [HttpGet] [HttpPost] tagged methods
}
```

and in my Startup.cs file I have added `services.AddSingleton<StationService>();`

Edit:

My QueueService class looks like this

```
public class QueueService : IQueueService
{

    #region Events
    static public event EventHandler<OnQueueAdvancePositionEventArgs> OnQueueAdvancePosition;
    private readonly OnQueueAdvancePositionEventArgs advancePositionArgs;
    #endregion


    private readonly IMongoCollection<BookingQueue> queueCollection;

    public QueueService(IBookingDbSettings settings)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);

        queueCollection = database.GetCollection<BookingQueue>(settings.CollectionName);

        advancePositionArgs = new OnQueueAdvancePositionEventArgs();
    }
// Various methods
}
```

Comment: is your event property marked as event? can you show how you define it in class? i mean is it `public event SomeEventType OnQueueAdvancePosition;`

Comment: I have defined it like this
`static public event EventHandler<OnQueueAdvancePositionEventArgs> OnQueueAdvancePosition;`
        inside the QueueService class